# Hiding entries in a dc.js pie chart/legend if they have 0 value

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, dc.js

When using a Pie Chart in dc.js, is there a way to hide a pie slice if the value is 0?

In the code that I use to generate my pie chart, you can see that my key is an object with a number of metrics within. If the given metric has a value of 0, I want to hide the pie slice from the chart.

```
Summary.prototype.drawPie = function (name, metric, selector, labelFormatter) {
  var chart = dc.pieChart(selector, this.chartGroup);

  chart.width(200).height(200)
    .slicesCap(7)
    .dimension(this.dimension)
    .group(this.group)
    .valueAccessor(function (d) { return d.value[metric]; })
    .legend(dc.legend().x(10).y(225).gap(5).horizontal(true).itemWidth(100).legendWidth(200))
    .minAngleForLabel(.75)
    .label(function (d) {
      if (d.key == 'Others') {
        return labelFormatter(d.value);
      } else {
        return labelFormatter(d.value[metric]);
      }
    })
    .title (function (d) {
      var value = (d.key == 'Others' ? d.value : d.value[metric]);
      return d.key + ': ' + labelFormatter(value);
    })
    .ordering(function (d) { return 0-d.value[metric]; });
  this.charts[name] = chart;
  chart.render();
}
```

Comment: I can think of a few ways to do this with plain d3, but I'm not sure of an easy syntax for dc.js.  What aspect of the chart is problematic?    If the pie slice is zero width it doesn't really display, anyway, so is it throwing off your `slicesCap` or do you want to hide it from the legend.  Maybe the specific problem could be fixed even while leaving zero-width slices in the chart...

Comment: I want the source hidden from the legend. I'm assuming I'll probably have to do a little customization to get the legend to hide the field, but figured I would ask the masses first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dc.js 2.0 has a `.data()` function on the base mixin which will allow you to pre-filter the groups in most cases.

It works for pie charts but it can interfere with capping.

[`BaseMixin.data()` docs](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#data)

See this issue for an example:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/494

A more general but uglier solution is the [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups).

Comment: Link is broken. I guess this can be found in https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/docs/old-api-docs/api-2.0.0.md

Comment: Thanks @Pygirl, it’s fixed. This is a very old answer, and was slightly outdated and incorrect, so I’ve updated it.